# Why does a wall plug show only 20V instead of 120V?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have two outlets that test at 20V, or sometimes 60V.  They should be 120V.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage?

Comment: Does a lamp plugged into either of these outlets light up normally?

Comment: If you're using a battery powered multimeter, I suggest you change the battery and see what number you get.

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong. Considering the amount of detail provided that is the best I can do.

Comment: I'm using a multimeter that shows the other outlets are fine.  It won't run the vacuum, didn't try a light and I'm not there now.  I replaced the one with a GFI and it can't be reset.  There is one other GFI outlet on the same breaker and it works fine.

Comment: You might have a broken or damaged wire in the wall (maybe it was smashed flat when hammering in an NM stable?) causing intermittent or weak conductivity.

Comment: OR a broken or damaged switch on that circuit that's passing some current. That could be a very unsafe situation. Try changing switches and making sure all connections are secure.